# lpData not get value after RegQueryValueEx

Tags: c++, registry

I'm not sure where problem is occur.
I have demo code get value from an registry:

```
using namespace std;

typedef struct REGKEYS
{
    HKEY hKey;
    LPCTSTR subKey;
    LPCTSTR value;
    LPCTSTR name;
    LPCTSTR file;
    LPCTSTR tag;
} REGKEYS;

REGKEYS regkeys = {HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,"Software\\Internet Download Manager", "Serial", "IDM", NULL, NULL};
HKEY hKey;
LPBYTE szDataBuf;
DWORD dwSize;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    RegOpenKeyEx(regkeys.hKey, regkeys.subKey, 0, KEY_READ, &hKey);
    RegQueryValueEx(hKey, regkeys.value, NULL, NULL, szDataBuf, &dwSize);
    int lerr = GetLastError();

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

When debug, I see regkeys.hKey not point to anything (it need point to "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE", is it?).
And szDataBuf is empty.
(GetLastError() not help me - it return 0)

Anyone tell me where is problem and how to fix it?

**EDIT2:**

I edited my code to :

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    DWORD dwSize = 0;
    RegOpenKeyEx(regkeys.hKey, regkeys.subKey, 0, KEY_READ, &hKey);

    RegQueryValueEx(hKey, regkeys.value, NULL, NULL, NULL, &dwSize);
    char *szDataBuf = new char(dwSize);
    RegQueryValueEx(hKey, regkeys.value, NULL, NULL, (LPBYTE)szDataBuf, &dwSize);

    delete[] szDataBuf;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

I debug and see szDataBuf get right value, but my program break and get warning: warning C4244: 'initializing' : conversion from 'DWORD' to 'char', possible loss of data.

Comment: You have an error code. Have you looked into that? On second thought, I just remembered these functions don't use that and instead return the error code. You should get rid of the `GetLastError` call.

Comment: Those functions have return values for a reason, check them.

Comment: 0x80000002 is the correct value for HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE

Comment: Have you checked that you have a key called "Software\\Internet Download Manager"? I've just checked my registry and I don't have that key.

Comment: @john, It's probably because you don't have IDM installed.

Comment: @chris I'm sure, but does cristiano? Just asking the obvious questions.

Comment: @john, I sure it exist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, your error checking code is not correct. The registry functions all return Win32 error codes. You need to take notice of them and check for errors.

To be clear, `GetLastError` is no use because these functions do not call `SetLastError`. They return the error code directly. You must read the documentation carefully. There are often subtle differences in the way different parts of Win32 do error handling.

The code in your updated question is better, but it still fails to check for errors in the call to `RegOpenKeyEx`.

Now, beyond that you are not actually calling `RegQueryValueEx` correctly. You have not initialized `dwSize`, and you have not allocated `szDataBuf`. Since these are global variables, they will be zero initialised. So your call to `RegQueryValueEx` will indeed succeed if the value exists. But you cannot expect any value to arrive in the buffer since you did not allocate a buffer. You are passing `NULL` to the `lpData` parameter.

So, allocate a buffer. For instance:

```
char szDataBuf[128];
```

Initialise `dwSize`:

```
DWORD dwSize = sizeof(szDataBuf);
```

Then your call to `RegQueryValueEx` should be

```
int lerr = RegQueryValueEx(hKey, regkeys.value, NULL, NULL, 
    (LPBYTE)szDataBuf, &dwSize);
```

Although you may wish to allocate the buffer dynamically:

```
dwSize = 0;
int lerr = RegQueryValueEx(hKey, regkeys.value, NULL, NULL, NULL, &dwSize);
// check lerr here
vector<char> szDataBuf(dwSize);
int lerr = RegQueryValueEx(hKey, regkeys.value, NULL, NULL, 
    (LPBYTE)&szDataBuf[0], &dwSize);
// check lerr here
```

You might also consider avoiding the use of global variables here. All of the variables you use would be make more sense as locals.

Comment: Thank you very much!!! It work, but if I adjust a bit, i has problem as describe in EDIT2. Can you explain for me and how to fix? (when i use "static" allocate a buffer).

Comment: Your use of new is wrong. It should be `char *szDataBuf = new char[dwSize];`